# Fetch results from two queries in single list in DAO class

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to fetch two different select queries in DAO class as single list in java.

```
public List<SBCDocumentDetailsVO> getsBCDetails() throws DataAccessException, SQLException{
List<SBCDocumentDetailsVO> sbcDocList = new ArrayList<SBCDocumentDetailsVO>();


MapSqlParameterSource namedParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource();

//using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for querying
sbcDocList = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(
        sbcDetailsQuery, namedParameter,
        new sBCDetailsMapper());
return sbcDocList;
```

}

my select queries are

```
SELECT State, marketId, COUNT(marketId)
FROM BatchReport
GROUP BY State, marketID


SELECT
SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd 
,SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'gr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountGrp
FROM BatchReport
```

Could any one help me to get the 2 queries in a single list.

Comment: you want a simple union? In the simplest way you could just create a `new ArrayList()` and invoke `addAll(resultList)` for each of your query result.

Comment: i think i can't use union here.find the below query.
SELECT State, marketId, COUNT(marketId)
FROM BatchReport
GROUP BY State, marketID



SELECT
SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd 
,SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'gr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountGrp
FROM BatchReport

Comment: could you plz prove an example.

Comment: I just created a demo in sql fiddle for your case, checck my answer

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view you have two possibilities:

---

**Collection Merge**

The idea is to execute both queries and add both results into a single list:

```
...
List result = new ArrayList();
result.addAll(firstQuery());
result.addAll(secondQuery());
...
```

---

**SQL UNION**

For SQL Union you will have one query that will be used to retrieve the entire result list. You can check how to do it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

In your case couldn't you do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   State, 
   marketId, 
   COUNT(marketId) 
FROM 
   BatchReport 
GROUP BY 
   State, 
   marketID 
UNION
SELECT 
   'Total', 
   SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd,
   SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'gr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountGrp 
FROM BatchReport
```

---

I would invest time in the SQL UNION solution since it solves the problem by quering the database just once.

You can see a **DEMO** here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5285/1

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach can be to create a single query and create a single bean with all the columns.
Following query should help:

```
SELECT State, marketId, COUNT(marketId),SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd ,SUM(CASE marketID WHEN 'gr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountGrp
FROM BatchReport
GROUP BY State, marketID
```

Pardon me for my syntax [I work on oracle]

Comment: Hi...I tried with this query.but its not giving the total for totalCountInd and totalCountgr column..

Comment: it will give totalcount per state, per marketid. This is not what you want?